# Blue Screen Error Stop Code : CRITICAL STRUCTURE CORRUPTION

Tags: windows-10, bsod

[image: As in this image]

I was using pc while I encountered with this blue screen error, I tried Windows Defender Quick Scan and also did the clean boot and also tried the update. Nothing worked out. Whats the best solution to solve this problem.

Comment: You should make available an image of the screen; there is often other information that might be helpful in diagnosing your problem, and therefore offering useful advice.

Comment: yes sure, I will upload now

Comment: I had DSP_WATCHDOG_VOILATION

Comment: That's actually DPC, "deferred procedure call".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DSP Watchdog triggers on very long hardware-level interrupts and deferred procedure calls that take too long. So you probably have a driver problem.

"Msrpc" is listed in your screenshot. RPC = "remote procedure call". My limited understanding is that these are not network related *per se* (local software may use them), but they use a client-server model than can be extended to networking (or conversely, they are a networking model that can be used in the special case a client and server on one host). The model is set up so that the software making the calls needs little or no knowledge of the current network topology.

So you should try updating your network drivers, and then your motherboard infrastructure drivers.

RPC is also attacked quite often by malware, and corrupt memory structures may be a symptom of malware.

It may also be memory errors: if you have mismatched memory installed, check the timings in the BIOS to ensure the auto-sensed settings are correct for all memory installed.

Comment: It crashes only when my pc ideal